# Display column with no record in OpenERP 7 Kanban View

Tags: odoo, kanban

I want to ask something here about Kanban View in OpenERP 7,

I'm creating a Kanban view for my module.
the view is grouped by 4 stage of columns, so when I drag a record to another column the 
stage of that record will be changed.

**but here's the problem:**

I want to drag a record from stage A to stage B.
but when there's no record in stage B the stage B's column will not be displayed until I've a record with stage B ,
so I can't change the stage by dragging the record because the stage B's column is not visible

is there any solution for this problem ?
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue, and this is the solution :

You can achieve that with **_group_by_full** dictionnary, to add in your osv.osv class.

By example, in project.py, you can find that :

> _group_by_full = {
>       'stage_id': **_read_group_stage_ids**,
>       'user_id': _read_group_user_id, }

The method **_read_group_stage_ids** return task_types from project ID if any project is passed in the context, or only the task_types from tasks.

But you can also do that you want : send all stages whenever your method, described in **_group_by_full** for your field stage is called.